# How can I INSERT into this table?

Tags: sql, ssms, database-administration

I have set a trigger up which I need to test. To do this I need to carry out an insert into the tblSOLine table however when I do this I am getting an error which I assume relates to the way the PK/FKs are set up. Is there any way I could do an insert into this table without messing with the table relationships?

Here is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO tblSOLine (SOHeaderID, ProductID, Quantity, NetSale, VAT)
VALUES (5364, 6, 6, NULL, NULL)
```

Here is the error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblSOLine_tblSOHeader". 
The conflict occured in database "VintageSounds", table "dbo.tblSOHeader", column 'SOHeaderID'.
```

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Comment: A row has to exist in the tblSOHeader table with the SOHeaderID of 5364.  A row has to exist in the tblProduct table with the ProductID of 6.  If neither of those rows exists, they have to be INSERTED before you can INSERT your tblSOLine row.

Comment: So if I try to insert with a value that exists that it throws a duplication error. Is what I am asking impossible?

Comment: @joehelsing : as Gilbert said, these records need to exist in the foreign table first if that is a constraint. If 5364 is not in SOHeader as a SOHeaderID already insert it there. If 6 is not already included as a ProductID in tblProduct, insert that there. Once both those records exist in the foreign table, you original insert should work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `SOHeaderID = 5364` does not exist in `SOHeader`.  You need to be sure that this value is what you intend.

You should not be getting an error if you attempt to insert this a headerid with this number, if the foreign key does not work.  However, such ids are usually `IDENTITY` columns, so they are automatically generated.  If you don't have a typo in the number, then perhaps you are confusing the number with something else, such as the customer number.